# Finding the distribution of the reciprocal of a random variable

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ be an exponentially distributed random variable. 
That is it has the probability density function
$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ and cumulative distribution function
$$F_X(x)=\int_ {0}^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}=[-e^{-\lambda x}]_{0}^x=1-e^{-\lambda x}$$

Let $Y:= \frac{1}{X}$. We have for $F_Y(x)$:
$$F_Y(x)=\mathbb{P}({Y \leq x})=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{X}\leq x\right )=\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq\frac{1}{x}\right )=1-\mathbb{P}\left(X < \frac{1}{x} \right)=^!1-F_X\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

The problem at $!$ is that definition of cumulative density function requires a non strict inequality so I don't know why this holds.
Aside from that, how does one get the **distribution** of $Y$ from the cumulative density function/probability density function? How do we deal with $Y$ at $X=0$ (does $X$ attain $0$ as a value even)

Comment: For continuous r.v. $\mathbb P\{X<x\}=\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}$.

Comment: Does the support being positive mean the image of $X$ is positive?

Comment: The central issue that answers both of your questions is that for a continuous random variable $X$ and any fixed number $a$, $\mathbb P(X = a) = 0$. This is why $\mathbb P(X \leq c) = \mathbb P(X < c)$ -- after all, $\{X \leq c\} = \{X < c\} \cup \{X = c\}$ and the union is disjoint -- and why you don't have to worry about whether or not $X$ might be $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that 
$$\left(-\infty, \dfrac{1}{x}\right) \cup \left\{\dfrac{1}{x} \right\}=\left(-\infty, \dfrac{1}{x} \right]$$
and that the sets $\left(-\infty, \dfrac{1}{x}\right)$, $\left\{\dfrac{1}{x} \right\}$ are disjoint.

Therefore, on the left-hand side, 
$$\mathbb{P}\left[\left(-\infty, \dfrac{1}{x}\right) \cup \left\{\dfrac{1}{x} \right\}\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\left(-\infty, \dfrac{1}{x}\right) \right] + \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\dfrac{1}{x} \right\}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X < \dfrac{1}{x}\right)+0$$
because
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\dfrac{1}{x} \right\}\right) = 0$$
due to $X$ being a continuous random variable, and on the right-hand side, we simply have
$$\mathbb{P}\left[\left(-\infty, \dfrac{1}{x} \right] \right] = \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$
Hence, equating the two sides,
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \dfrac{1}{x}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X < \dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for addressing the continuity issue. What can we say about the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: @whycantihavealongername Well, from your work, you have $F_Y(x) = 1 - F_X(1/x) = 1-(1-e^{-\lambda/x}) = e^{-\lambda / x}$. You can use this to find the PDF by taking the derivative if you need it. I don't know if there's a standard name for this distribution.

Comment: @whycantihavealongername I suppose you could call it an "inverse exponential distribution:" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_exponential_distribution