# What is the expected value of the reciprocal of an exponentially distributed random variable?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\lambda$. What is $E[X^{-1}]$?

The only online resource I've been able to locate that speaks to the issue directly is this [Wikipedia stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution), which states "Note that the expected value of this random variable does not exist."

I assume this may stem from the fact that $X$ isn't strictly positive, causing a division by zero  and a $(-\infty) + \infty$ to appear somewhere in the expectation value integral?

If so, what is the significance of $E[X^{-1}]$ "not existing" from a statistical standpoint? If one generates $n$ exponentially-distributed data and compute the mean of their reciprocals, what does one expect to get as $n \to \infty$? I take it the limit never converges to anything, even $\infty$?

Comment: No, it does not come from division by zero, but that $\int_{(0,\infty)} y\,\mathrm{d}(e^{-\lambda/y})=\infty$ from the contribution near $y=\infty$ looking like $\int^\infty \frac1y(1+o(1)) \,\mathrm{d}y$.

Comment: $E(\frac{1}{X})=a\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}}{x}dx=\infty$.

Comment: To answer directly the Q in your last paragraph: Any finite sample of positive observations will have a mean, but that mean may fluctuate greatly depending on the particular sample chosen (in particular how close some values get to 0). // If I use R to get a sample of a million from an exponential population with mean 10 (rate 0.1), as follows `x = rexp(10^6, 0.1); mean(1/x)`, then I get answers 1.66, 1.86, 1.75, 14,49, 1.64, 1.46, ..., rounded to 2 places. By contrast, for a process with a stable mean, sample mean of a million observations should match population mean correct to 2-3 places.

Comment: ... If I use delayed exponential dist'n with support $[1,∞)$ then R code `x = 1+rexp(10^6, 0.1); mean(1/x)` consistently returns values between 0.201 and 0.202.  // Perhaps see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760468/finding-the-distribution-of-the-reciprocal-of-a-random-variable?rq=1), marked as 'Relevant' in the margin of your question.